# C++ OOP Class for vector of vectors

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, vector

I am quite new to the concept of OOP and I want to create a generic class **Board** which can create multiple different matrices objects.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> >board;

void setup(int board_size) {
    // fill inner vector
    for (int i = 0; i < board_size; i++) {
        vector<int>temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < board_size; j++) {
            temp.push_back(1);
        }
        board.push_back(temp);
    }
}

void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << board[i][j];
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

```
int main()
{
    setup(3);
    setup(5);
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

I want to improve my code in an OOP way so that I have a class **Board** which can create multiple different matrices by using **setup** function.

And that I can later display each matrices by using the **display** function.

For example:

```
Board board_1;
Board board_2;

board_1.display();
board_2.display();
```

I am not quite sure how to achieve this, any help would be very appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You get much better response here if you try something and show your attempt (no matter how broken or incomplete). Anything helps, currently it is not completely clear what prevents you from defining a class with `board` as member and `display` and `setup` as member functions. Thats bascially all you have to do to get started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, all you have to do is wrap a class around the code you already have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Board {
vector<vector<int> >board;
public:
Board(int board_size) {//constructor as per suggestion
  setup(board_size);
}

void setup(int board_size) {//setup now also allows you to change the board-size later
    board.clear();//removing existing elements
    // fill inner vector
    for (int i = 0; i < board_size; i++) {
        vector<int>temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < board_size; j++) {
            temp.push_back(1);
        }
        board.push_back(temp);
    }
}

void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << board[i][j];
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
}
};
```

And that's it. Now you can call it like this:

```
Board board_1 = Board(3);
Board board_2 = Board(5);


board_1.display();
board_2.display();

//change board-size and display them again
board_1.setup(6);
board_2.setup(10);


board_1.display();
board_2.display();
```

Also, maybe separate declaration (in .hpp-file) from implementation (in .cpp-file)

Comment: Also, as I wrote in my answer, I'm pretty sure that `std::vector` isn't what he is looking for, but `std::array`.

Comment: @Kerek I agree that in most cases, the board-size won't vary after instantiation so `std::array` works fine, but we don't know if that is the case for OP. Also, since he's new to OOP, i wanted to keep my answer as close to his code as possible. Introducing new conepts like templates when he's not yet clear on how to declare a class might be a bit much...

Comment: @Kerek well that depends. In your answer `Board<3>` and `Board<4>` are distinct types with no relation. In case you want to have eg a `std::vector<Board>` with `Boards` of different size, then `std::vector` would be much more convenient

Comment: @idclev463035818 The solution is very simple. If you want to have a vector of boards of different size (which seems a big weird to me...), you can declare an interface without a template, and have it inheriting from that. Using a std::vector to hide this isn't a good practice IMO, since std::vector supports changing the board size on the run, which isn't the case for most (if not all) of the board games I know of.

Comment: @Kerek I know how to do that. Note that OP wrote:  "generic class Board which can create multiple different matrices objects. " without further clarification I would take that literally, which means one class different matrices. That this is for a board game with fixed board size is speculations. But nevermind, it doesnt hurt to have both alternatives for OP to read

Comment: @Kerek even the title says "Class for vector of vectors". Sorry, I'll shut up now ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yea, I know that he wanted vectors, but it doesn't mean he ***needed*** vectors... It is more up to your taste, I personally prefer the array version.

Answer (score 1):

I have few suggestions about your code:

1. Using `std::vector` means that the size of the board can change during runtime, which shouldn't be true (in most games...). In order to create a board with fixed size, but that can be initialize in different sizes (meaning, you pick the size once, and it cannot change), you can use `std::array` with class template, that is determined on compile time, and cannot be changed!
2. Your setup function, is actually a constructor of the class Board, therefore, instead of creating a board using it, make it your default constructor.

Look at the following example, with usage examples:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

template <uint64_t SIZE>
class Board
{
public:
    Board()
    {
        // Here you initialize the board
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        {
            for (uint64_t j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
            {
                board_rep[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    };

    void display() const
    {
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "| ";
            for (uint64_t j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
            {
                std::cout << board_rep[i][j] << " |";
            }

            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    std::array<std::array<int, SIZE>, SIZE> board_rep;
};


int main()
{
    Board<3> small_board{};
    Board<5> big_board{};

    std::cout << "small board:\n\n" << std::endl;
    small_board.display();
    std::cout << "big board:\n\n" << std::endl;
    big_board.display();
}
```